# Create container with routing tables

Tags: docker

I have two stations A and B. I want to redirect all the traffic comming from A in direction of B and reciprocally.
Is there an image docker with this capabilities?
I tried to use [quagga](https://anton-baranov.blogspot.com/2015/03/using-quagga-with-docker-containers.html), but apparently it doesn't exists anymore.

Thanks for the help,

Warok

Comment: What kind of traffic is that? HTTP(S)?

Comment: Http/https, or whatever I want, (if possible, else, juste Https)

Comment: Have you considered using something like `nginx-proxy`?

Comment: Nope, (sorry I'm a beginner with Docker)

Comment: This isn’t a core Docker feature.  If you want to configure `iptables` by hand you have that option.